# CTE: SELECT statement to read rows made by an INSERT Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a CTE that first inserts rows, and then reads the table with the inserted rows. Right now, the read on the table *does not* take into account the inserted rows.

The simplest example could be like this:

The Table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (column1 text, column2 text);
```

The query:

```
WITH insert_first AS (
    INSERT INTO mytable (column1, column2)
    VALUES ('value1', 'value2')
    RETURNING *
), select_after AS (
  SELECT * FROM mytable
  LEFT JOIN insert_first ON insert_first.column1 = mytable.column1
) SELECT * FROM select_after
```

Here, select_after will be empty.

I thought by doing a LEFT JOIN on `insert_first`, I would hint to SQL to wait for the insert. But, it does not seem to do this.

Is there a way I could make a query that runs over `mytable`, which sees the inserts made from `insert_first`?

Here's a playground too: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/6796

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? These CTE queries run in parallel so that's why you can't achieve what you want.

Comment: Have you considered replacing `mytable` in your second CTE with `(SELECT * FROM mytable UNION ALL SELECT * FROM insert_first) mytable`? Not sure what your ultimate goal is, but I think it will work fine for your sample scenario.

Comment: Remove the second CTE and just do `SELECT * FROM insert_first` . See modified fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/6797.

Comment: @EdmCoff the UNION ALL could work! My main worry with that, is that Postgres may do something weird and materialize `mytable`.  I think that will do the trick!

Comment: From docs [WITH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH): *The primary query and the WITH queries are all (notionally) executed at the same time. This implies that the effects of a data-modifying statement in WITH cannot be seen from other parts of the query, other than by reading its RETURNING output. If two such data-modifying statements attempt to modify the same row, the results are unspecified.*

Comment: Understood, thank you team! Okay, I can either go with UNION ALL or split these up into two separate queries inside one transaction.

Comment: CTE's have very fun way to work, if you dont describe the insert_first CTE on the select query the CTE will not get executed,CTE's not used does not get executed, this is because you are using a left join. if it is a JOIN this very rare scenario would not happen.
 you should make a JOIN or subquery on the SELECT * FROM select_after query to reclaim all the inserts from the insert_first CTE , then your execution order would not get unexpected results.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153458/postgresql-function-not-executed-when-called-from-inside-cte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Adrian mentioned in the comments, this is not possible:

> From docs WITH: The primary query and the WITH queries are all (notionally) executed at the same time. This implies that the effects of a data-modifying statement in WITH cannot be seen from other parts of the query, other than by reading its RETURNING output. If two such data-modifying statements attempt to modify the same row, the results are unspecified.